# "e.force:createRecord" is not returning a boolean value for lightning framework specialist superbadge challenge 2

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I am trying to complete challenge 2 of Lightning Framework specialist.

The form’s controller checks whether the event.force:createRecord event is supported by a standalone app and either shows or hides the New button according to best practices.

I am using the followign piece of code for the above requirement.

In Lightning Component

```
<aura:attribute name="isNewEnabled" type="Boolean"/>

<aura:if isTrue = "{!v.isNewEnabled}">
            <lightning:layoutItem flexibility="grow">
                <lightning:button label="New" class="slds-button slds-button_neutral"/>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </aura:if>
```

In Lightning Component Js Controller

```
var isEnabled = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
        console.log('**8&&&&'+$A.get('e.force:createRecord'));
        if(isEnabled){
            component.set(isNewEnabled, true);
        }
```

However, the console is printing the value as undefined as a result of which the button is not being rendered in my desktop.

Is this the correct way to implement the above?

Comment: Where are you testing the same in Lightning Application OR in the tab?

Comment: I am testing in a lightning application.

Comment: In Lightning Application, you will not get the Event and this is the reason that you are getting undefined in the Debug. test the same in Lightning using the tab as described in requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You are doing it in the correct way. Are you testing in **Lightning Application** as In Lightning Application, you will not get the Event and this is the reason that you are getting undefined in the console.? test the same in Lightning using the tab as described in requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you are setting the attribute value you need to provide the value provider i.e.

```
component.set("v.isNewEnabled", true);
```